# Loop through Mysql Results

Tags: python, mysql, database

This is the code I have:

```
r = ''
while True:
    data = result.fetch_row()
    r+= record[0][0] + record[0][1] + record[0][0]
print r
```

What I want to do is, first fetch all the rows:

```
data = result.fetch_row(0)
```

and then run a loop for "data"

rather than do it within the while loop.

Comment: Your ``if->elif`` test is redundant. ``None`` always evaluates to ``False``, so there's no need to test for that condition separately.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam; your question is not specific to Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.x or to mod_wsgi, so leave those tags off.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you also included the actual Python library you used to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop *over the cursor itself*:

```
for row in result:
    # do something with row
```

Iteration over cursors is optional in the [Python DB-API 2 specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), but in practice all current implementations support it.

This gives the database adapter the freedom to fetch rows from the database server in batches, as needed.

If you do stumble on a database adapter that doesn't support iteration over a cursor, then you can always fall back to `cursor.fetch_all()`:

```
for row in cursor.fetch_all():
    # do something with row
```

However, take into account that this'll load the whole result set into a list.

Answer (score -1):

What are you using? pyodbc? In most apis you can use fetchall().

See this: [pyodbc api](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) and search for fetchall()